# Trouble calling args in another method

Tags: java, methods, args

Pretty new here in java. I'm trying to add methods to my otherwise currently working program to print out amount of characters from an args array. Trying to install a new method, I'm having trouble with calling args. This is my current code, and the red outline is.

```
static void amountOfCharsInSentence() {
    int sum=0;
    for (String s: args) {  //args on this line is marked red
        sum+=s.length();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   amountOfCharsInSentence();
}
```

Any hint or tips in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is an argument to `main`, which means you can only use that argument (which is like a local variable) within `main`.

If you want to use it elsewhere, you have two options. The most suitable is to pass it to your other function as an argument:

```
static void amountOfCharsInSentence(String[] args) {
// Declare argument here -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int sum=0;
    for (String s: args) {  // `args` here is the argument to *this* function
        sum+=s.length();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    amountOfCharsInSentence(args);
    // Pass it here --------^^^^
}
```

Your other option is to create a static member of your class, which all methods in your class have access to, and assign `args` to that static member:

```
class YourClass {

    static String[] commandLineArgs;

    static void amountOfCharsInSentence() {
        int sum=0;
        for (String s: commandLineArgs) { // Use the static member here
            sum+=s.length();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        commandLineArgs = args;           // Assign the static member here
        amountOfCharsInSentence();
    }
}
```

...but that's probably not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the args.

```
static void amountOfCharsInSentence(String[] args) {
int sum=0;
for (String s: args) {  //now it will not give red line. 
                        // red line is indicated because there is no args inside this method
    sum+=s.length();
}
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  amountOfCharsInSentence(args);
 }
```

Hope this solves your problem